# How to increase disk space in root?

Tags: linux, centos, root

So I check on my server using `df -h` and my centos-root is at 99% capacity.

Just a few days ago, the root was at 87%. For some reason, it increases so quick. Is there any suggestions on how to reduce the used space?

```
[root@host ~]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   50G  713M  99% /
devtmpfs                 3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.8G  401M  3.4G  11% /run
tmpfs                    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home  873G  136G  738G  16% /home
/dev/sda1                494M  172M  323M  35% /boot
```

```
[root@host ~]# du -csh /*
0       /bin
146M    /boot
0       /dev
23M     /etc
136G    /home
0       /lib
0       /lib64
0       /media
0       /mnt
24K     /nginxweblog
990M    /opt
du: cannot access `/proc/61778/task/61778/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/61778/task/61778/fdinfo/4': No such file of directory
du: cannot access `/proc/61778/fd/4': No such file of directory
du: cannot access `/proc/61778/fdinfo/4': No such file of directory
0       /proc
41M     /root
401M    /run
0       /sbin
0       /srv
0       /sys
376K    /tmp
2.6G    /usr
14G     /var
153G    total
```

```
[root@host ~]# cd /; du -sh * 2> /dev/null
0       bin
146M    boot
0       dev
23M     etc
136G    home
0       lib
0       lib64
0       media
0       mnt
24K     nginxweblog
990M    opt
0       proc
41M     root
401M    run
0       sbin
0       srv
0       sys
376K    tmp
2.6G    usr
14G     var
```

```
[root@host ~]# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  centos   1   3   0 wz--n- 931.02g    0
```

```
[root@host ~]# cd /var/log
[root@host log]# ls
anaconda       cron           dmseg      lastlog           maillog-20160201   messages-20160124  ppp              secure-20160124   spooler-20160124  yum.log
audit          cron-20160111  dmesg.old  maillog           mariadb            messages-20160201  samba            secure-20160201   spooler-20160201  yum.log-20150101
boot.log       cron-20160117  firewalld  maillog-20160111  messages           nginx              secure           spooler           tallylog          yum.log-20160101
btmp           cron-20160124  grubby     maillog-20160117  messages-20160111  ntpstats           secure-20160111  spooler-20160111  tuned
btmp-20160201  cron-20160201  httpd      maillog-20160124  messages-20160117  php-fpm            secure-20160117  spooler-20160117  wtmp
```

```
[root@host ~]# du -csh /var/*
0       /var/adm
1.3M    /var/cache
0       /var/crash
36K     /var/db
0       /var/empty
0       /var/games
0       /var/gopher
0       /var/kerberos
13G     /var/lib
0       /var/local
0       /var/lock 
90M     /var/log
0       /var/mail
0       /var/nis
0       /var/opt
0       /var/preserve
0       /var/run
51M     /var/spool
4.0K    /var/tmp
0       /var/var
4.0K    /var/www
0       /var/yp
14G     total
```

```
[root@host andi]# du -csh /var/lib/*
64K     /var/lib/alternatives
8.0K    /var/lib/authconfig
0       /var/lib/cs
0       /var/lib/dav
0       /var/lib/dbus
0       /var/lib/dhclient
0       /var/lib/dnsmasq
0       /var/lib/games
0       /var/lib/initial-setup
0       /var/lib/initramfs
4.0K    /var/lib/logrotate.status
0       /var/lib/misc
13G     /var/lib/mysql
8.0K    /var/lib/NetworkManager
40K     /var/lib/nginx
0       /var/lib/ntp
0       /var/lib/os-prober
320K    /var/lib/pear
64K     /var/lib/php
0       /var/lib/phpMyAdmin
4.0K    /var/lib/plymouth
0       /var/lib/polkit-1
4.0K    /var/lib/postfix
4.0K    /var/lib/rhsm
58M     /var/lib/rpm
0       /var/lib/rpm-state
4.0K    /var/lib/rsyslog
0       /var/lib/samba
0       /var/lib/stateless
16K     /var/lib/systemd
0       /var/lib/tpm
0       /var/lib/udisks2
0       /var/lib/upower
0       /var/lib/virtuoso
13M     /var/lib/yum
13G     total
```

Comment: Log files should *never* show up in your root partition (unless you have only one). Check how to rotate/truncate logs automatically in your distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The outputs of **du** and **df** don't line up in terms of used disk; search for deleted files that are being written to. Stop (restart) the process writing to the file(s), or reboot the box.

```
 lsof | awk '/deleted/ && $5 ~ /w/'
```

Implement log rotation and find out why the log keeps growing at that tremendous rate (and rectify the root cause).

Comment: I did `service nginx restart` but it didn't reduce anything.

Comment: That's surprising. Can you check what the parent process of the php-process was that held the file? See if you can restart **that** instead.

Comment: actually after i did `service php-fpm restart` it went down from 99% to 34%. Thanks for this! But I'm guessing this is a temporary solution only though. What do you think?

Comment: Whoever set the machine up failed to implement log rotation. So yes, in this case it's temporary. But extending filesystems (shuffling disk about) won't make it go away, it will just postpone it. Implement log rotation. :}

Answer (score 0):

Short answer; increase space either by removing data or increase the actual size of root filesystem.

**Long answer;**

When you have such a big disk at your expense and you are using lvm as well, it is encouraged that you crate separate file systems for /var, /tmp, /var/log, /opt etc.

First of all, find what is eating your disk space by running the following as root
`cd /; du -sh * 2> /dev/null`

Looks like you have already run the command.

I can see that /var is taking too much space, probably it will be a good idea to put it on a separate filesystem. Can you share output of `vgs' command?

Here are the steps you need to take; [Detailed steps here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html)

- Reboot the system, press any key at grub menu and append the following to the kernel line `systemd.unit=rescue.target`
- It will ask for root password, type the root password in
- `lvchange --activate y`
- `lvreduce -r -L 800G /dev/mapper/centos-home` you can specify new size 700G, 800G
- `lvextend -r -L 100G /dev/mapper/centos-root` say you want to make root as 100G file system
  Don't forget -r option, otherwise you will have to run resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-root

Comment: All right, you dont have any free space on your volume group. Are you willing to shrink /home file-system? If yes, I can show you how to do that and then we can either use that free space to create another /var file-system or assign that extra space to / file-system.

Comment: We can expand a LVM online but shrinking is another problem. I am guessing that you are using CENTOS, is it 6 or 7? Because the process is going to differ slightly. Also, you will need to have root user's password.

Comment: Before you guys start resizing filesystems I'd like to point out that the space used in **du** and **df** is way out of whack. I'd suggest looking for deleted files that are still being written to first.  Just saying ...

Comment: @tink any way to look for the deleted/hidden unused files?

Comment: @Joey2890 : sure **lsof | awk '/deleted/ && $5 ~ /w/'** should do the job...

Comment: @tink this is the output: php-fpm 1646 root 3w REG 253,1 34984724600 204093108 /var/log/php-fpm/error.log (deleted)

Comment: @Joey2890 : well that looks like a rather fat file there :}  if you can: restarting the web-service you're running on that box will clear a ton of space. Or rebooting the box if it's just YOUR dev box and you don't want to try to restart the service individually...

Comment: @tink is it `service nginx restart` or `service nginx reload`? what's the downside of doing this?

Comment: @Joey2890: restart; reload doesn't hang-up running processes, it just fetches configuration options.  Downside is that active sessions to the web-service will drop.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question provided the following solution:

> FINAL EDIT: found the solution (temporary one at least). Did a `service php-fgm restart` function and it reduced the storage from 99% to 34%. But guess I'd have to do log rotation and other things to my server to get a more permanent solution.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you have a big *mysql* database and a small partition so you could either repartition using *Gparted* or change the place where *mysql* saves its data to /home, which is sometimes not safe(hacking) or buggy.

To change the place where *mysql* saves its data:

*assuming the new directory is `/home/mynewsqldir`*

**1.** Obvious enough.

`service stop mysql`

**2.** copy your database to the new position

`cp -R /var/lib/mysql /home/mynewsqldir`

`cp -R /var/lib/mysql/users /home/mynewsqldir`

**3.** Backup the *my.cnf* file

`cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf  /home/my.cnf.backup`

**4.** edit the original *my.cnf* file
and look for *datadir* and *socket* lines then replace them with

`datadir=/home/mynewsqldir`

`socket=/home/mynewsqldir`

**5.** update the directory permissions for safety

`chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mynewsqldir`

**6.** rename *mysql* directory in */var/lib/* to anything just in case something goes wrong but if everything goes as intended , you can delete it .

**7.** security thingie to update *Apparmor*

`ln -s /home/mynewsqldir/ /var/lib/mysql`

`echo "alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /home/mynewsqldir/," >> /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`

**8.** Reload the *apparmor* profiles and start *mysql*

`sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload`

`start mysql`

Comment: thank you for the guide. i restart my web server and for now the usage went down from 99% to 34%. But i have a feeling that it was only a temporary solution. I'll try your solution. Btw, i tried doing `yum update` and it says error cannot open package etc etc. do i have to install the GParted on my server/local computer first?

Comment: i think it is temporary too,but you should wait, if usage goes up again then you can try my guide. for *Gparted* https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5231 or generally search google **install gparted centos** as i have never owned a centos and i don't wanna break your system.

Comment: you could install it or just download *gpartedlive.iso* , then burn it to a usb using unetbootin or whatever, boot from it, and repartition which is better in my opinion and please delete all your `i did it` or `i edited` type of comment as they are very non useful

Comment: @user3566929 Are you kidding? A log file held > 60% of the disk-space in / and you suggest moving data base files around?

Comment: @tink where did you get it was log file?

Comment: @user3566929 : 6th comment to Zul's answer, and 3rd comment to mine... also var had used up 14GB of the 50 (not accounting for the log file), so moving the database seems ... ummm ... hasty, to say the least.

Comment: @tink oh, well they were after my answer so i missed them , that's all, besides, my var directory is about the same without mysql or any extra large log files,aynways doesn't a error log that big indicate that he has got some configuration wrong or is it just a bug?

Comment: @user3566929 : keep reading the comments to my answer ;}  Looks to me like logrotate is blissfully unaware of that file ..

Comment: @tink yeah but still logrotate is  just an enhancement or a mitigation and i have seen large log files but not such a large error file so doesn't that indicate he has a bigger problem?, when i answered him i had on my mind an instance where mysql parts kept crashing because of a permissions issue on some levels and generated large dumps that it ate away all the 1TB drive, but on the surface, nothing wrong was happening that the normal non-experienced sysadmin would notice

Comment: @user3566929 ... if you have ever growing data (be it data, logs, or dump files) anything is just mitigation. An ever growing error file on a dev box does not surprise me in the least, though. P.S.: Your answer was later than the comments above. ;}

Comment: @tink i have checked the timing cause i suspected myself and it was not

Comment: @tink ahh okay, so its better to create log rotation in your opinion? Ill definitely look into it. So is the gparted suggestion not a good idea?

Comment: @jj282890 : nothing wrong w/ gparted, but it's horses for courses.  If you are happy to have an ever growing log and keep adding disk to accommodate it, by all means ;} ... I'd have log rotation **and** try to find out why it's growing at the rate it's growing

Comment: @jj282890 i missed what **tink** got from the beginning because i thought it was just a growing database issue while he noticed it was just the error log file and now we both are on the same ground, you have to know what causes that much errors .

Comment: @tink i think you should edit your answer with your resolution and solution so he can accept your answer.